# Add time to rows in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to add values of duplicate rows in SQL Server. I want to some how do this in SSIS. This is how data looks

```
 SESSION ID  |TALK TIME|TSEC|TMIN |
 ------------+---------+----+-----+
 34000018959 |00:34.0  |34  |0.56 |
 34000018959 |20:29.0  |1229|20.48|
```

This is what output I would like to see:

```
 SESSION ID  |TALK TIME|TSEC|TMIN |
 ------------+---------+----+-----+
 34000018959 |21:03.0  |1263|21.05|
```

Is there a way I can do this in SSIS

Comment: What datatype is `TALK TIME`?

Comment: Why in SSIS?  Is the data in a table or a file?

Comment: If possible, use the GROUP BY directly in your source if on a database like SQL Server (will be a lot faster than SSIS). There is a Group By operation in SSIS in any case.

Comment: Guessing `TALK TIME` is a `varchar`, as `00:34.0` isn't a valid value for the `time` datatype.

Comment: If ur requirement is to do in SSIS write the query with the group by  and then place it in the Execute SQL Task.

Answer (score 2):

As Sujatha mentioned above, create an Execute SQL Task in your package and run the following code:

```
select session_id,  CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,sum(tsec),0),108) [Talk Time], sum(tsec)TSEC, sum(tmin)TMIN 
from yourtable 
group by session_id
```

Comment: Is there any way else. Other than using Execute SQL Task?

Comment: @AbdulquadirShaikh you can do this using a Script Component, but i think it is better to use Execute SQL Task